# How do I add a value from a button to an object?

Tags: javascript, express

I am working on a website where users can write articles. The user simply writes information into a form and selects the submit button and the article is saved. All the values from the form are saved thanks to the input tags however I am having some difficulty with setting up a category/tagging system. I want it where users can sort articles by category (TV, movies, music, etc.) but in order to do that, the article itself must have a category.

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Television", "Movie"],
  },
});
```

There is my article Schema. You can see it has a category section which has multiple options to select from.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p class="main__article-p">Select Tags</p>
    <div class="main__article-category">
      <button class="main__article-button">Television</button>
      <button class="main__article-button">Movie</button>
      <button class="main__article-button">Music</button>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Write Your Title</label>
        <input
          name="title"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content">Write Your Content</label>
        <textarea
          name="content"
          required
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author"></label>
        <input
          name="author"
          value="<%= author.username %>"
          hidden
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And there is my form. The only part the user doesn't fill out is the author which is hidden & is automatically filled out to the users username. The post itself is saved as an object.

At the very top of the form you'll notice a few buttons. I want it to where the user can select a button and whichever button they choose, that value will be added as the category but I am having a difficult time figuring out exactly how I can accomplish that.

And here is my post request in case it's needed.

```
exports.article_create_post = [
  // Validate and sanitize fields.
  body("title", "Title must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  body("content", "Content must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  body("author").trim().escape(),
  body("category").trim().escape(),
  // Process request after validation and sanitization.
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Extract the validation errors from a request.
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // Create a Book object with escaped and trimmed data.
    const article = new Article({
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
      author: req.body.author,
      category: req.body.category,
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // There are errors. Render form again with sanitized values/error messages.

      // Get all authors and genres for form.
      async.parallel((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.render("article_form", {
          title: "Create Article",
          author: author.username,
          content: content,
          category: category,
          article,
          errors: errors.array(),
        });
      });
      return;
    }

    // Data from form is valid. Save article.
    article.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      // Successful: redirect to new article record.
      res.redirect(article.url);
    });
  },
];
```